# WinGHCi won't start

Tags: haskell, crash, ghci, winghci

So, I tried to ":set prompt "λ> "" in WinGHCi, it crashed and after that wouldn't start again (Not Responding). I reinstalled the Haskell Platform and it still won't start (Not Responding). GHCi works in cmd. I searched for remaining .conf files before the first un/reinstall for WinGHCi that could make it crash but couldn't find any. I'll appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Try reporting an issue [here](http://code.google.com/p/winghci/issues/list).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WinGHCi stores its command history in the registry. Just delete everything under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Haskell\WinGHCi` from the registry (use `regedit`).

Additionally, please report this to the [developer](http://code.google.com/p/winghci/issues/list).

Comment: Thank you very much, I deleted the row which says GHCi_PROMPT_COMBO3 REG_SZ "λ> " and everything is back to normal with WinGHCi. :)